# UserControl with Design Time Data, but data not rendered when control used

Tags: wpf, user-controls, design-time-data

Hi I have a simple user control with some Blend generated design time data:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomerProfile.View.CustomerProfile"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CustomerProfile.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid Margin="8" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/CustomerProfileViewModelSampleData.xaml}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Surname" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Account.Surname}" />

</Grid>
```

This is all good, and when I open the user control in Blend or Cider I see the generated data.

However, I am using the UserControl in a Window, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cp="clr-namespace:CustomerProfile.View;assembly=CustomerProfile"
    Title="Demo" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <cp:CustomerProfile />
</Grid>
```

When I open this Window in Blend or Cider I do NOT see the design time data in the User Control.

Is there any way around this?  Am I going about things the wrong way?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does it make a difference if you move your `d:DataContext` to the `<UserControl>` tag instead of the `<Grid>`? Right now your design-time DataContext is inside your UserControl, instead of being part of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried that but exactly the same result.

Comment: what happens if you set `<cp:CustomerProfile d:DataContext.../>`

Comment: i think it may be because the Window's child controls "inherit" it's DataContext (which is nothing).  also, the designer takes the root control (`Window` when `Window` is being designed) into special consideration to others in the designer (root control's ctor does NOT execute).

Comment: Thanks @jberger.  I had a slight problem in setting <cp:CustomerProfile d:DataContext.../> because my UserControl is in a seperate project to the one with the main Window in.  And that seperate project is the one with the design time data!   BUT...just in the interest of trying it out I created a Window in the same project as my UserControl and design time data, and set the d:DataContext on that window, and yes it did display the data in the UserControl within the window.  Not sure where that leaves me really, I need the UserControl in a seperate project as it's a reusable control!

Comment: @jberger I found you can navigate through the folders in the reference to d:DataContext!  So I manually went in and set the Window design time DataContext to reference the data from the other project using "../" to move up to the parent folder. Like this: `<cp:CustomerProfile d:DataContext="{d:DesignData ../CustomerProfile/SampleData/CustomerProfileViewModelSampleData.xaml}" />`  worked a treat.  Thanks for the help!  (note that I had to do it manually in XAML I could not do it with drag & drop in Blend)

Comment: @jberger I spoke too soon, the solution no longer builds when I try and pull the design data in from the other project!!

Comment: @Paul: you can add the design data file **as a link** to your Window's project.  That way, when you edit the file in one project, it gets reflected to the other..

Comment: @jberger: I liked the idea, sounded like it would work. However the data does not display when the design data is added as a link to the Window's project.  The compiler underlines the `d:DesignData...` with a _file not found_ error.  I did set the Build Action of the linked file to "DesignData".

Comment: what happens if you: set your `<cp:CustomerProfile d:DataContext=...` and copy the sample data to your Window's project?

Comment: i'd suggest just doing that.  i don't consider sample data to be part of DRY, because it's really a designer preference.

Comment: @jberger : yeah I will live with it. Many thanks..!

Comment: I think you should cut the relevant bits from comments and form an answer, and accept it ;)